# What happens to Goetia when they can't manifest on Earth anymore?

Tags: lore, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

I'm currently in the process of trying to get as firm of a grasp on ephemeral beings as I can, and in the process of cataloging them for the sake of myself and my friends, I've been intrigued and puzzled by Goetia.

The major hang-up I'm having with them is that they possess no Manifestation abilities and have to be provided them by the mage. I've been reviewing the book several times to try and get a solid idea on how mages would do that, with the Bind Spirit, Revenant, and Familiar spells having various options, but Goetia don't even possess the Twilight Manifestation on their own.

What happens to them when the spell runs out and they cannot maintain any manifestation on Earth?

In the Astral Realms, sure, there's no problem, but with no means of manifesting on their own, why would Goetic Summons mention the Open condition? It's all very confusing.

I wish the book was more clear about this. The ephemeral system was already a bit of a chore to learn and these guys are giving me a headache. It stinks, considering how fun the concept of summoning characters from the public eye to fight on your behalf is.

Answer (score 2):

Even *in-universe*, it doesn't actually seem to be really understood exactly what happens to them *either*, as far as I can tell.

After all, the following is said:

> **Goetic demons dwell on no plane of existence known to mages**, but can manifest in Twilight as well as in the Material World. There are
>   only three ways of destroying a Goetic demon: a successful abjuration
>   by its summoner, raw magical force, or a solution to the emotional
>   problem that originally birthed the demon.

So, on what happens to them when they cannot manifest on Earth anymore?

They definitely do continue to *exist*, even if not on Earth or in the Twilight, but do so in an unknown plane that - given it's not known about - *cannot* be accessed or apparently even learned about by a Mage.

Which would be why the information on it is so vague.

Then there's also this little fact too, that merits a mention -

> If the host of a Goetic
>   demon dies, the creature is free to roam Astral Space and the Material
>   World of its own volition.

In this case, it doesn't matter if the spell runs out.

The Goetia creature can henceforth manifest themselves in the aforementioned places when they please.

Meaning any before barring from Earth, would presumably be null at this point and they would be able to come back from that/manifest again: unless they're destroyed.

(Citation Note: Quoted sources here are from the White Wolf wiki.)

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by mention which book you are quoting, and perhaps which page.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman...I'm a bit embarrassed to say so, but I do have to admit the exact quotations are from the WhiteWolf wiki. I hope that's not an issue.

Comment: No problem at all, but I would add that to the answer. References are always helpful, especially when providing direct quotes.